# How to change profile picture in Spotify?

Tags: profile-picture, spotify

Is there any way to change one's profile picture in Spotify?

Comment: If anyone knows of an update here, please lemme know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, it doesn't appear that is possible. See [the official feature request at the Spotify community page](http://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-Ideas/Picture-on-Profile/idi-p/11523).